What are the recurring states in this Markov Regime Switching Heston Model?
I'm a 3rd year Maths undergrad reading into topics I could do my Master's dissertation on (Mathematical Finance). I've already covered Markov chains and I found out about Hidden Markov Models applied to a Regime context.
I'm having trouble with figuring out what exactly are the states in
http://imar.ro/journals/Mathematical_Reports/Pdfs/2022/4/14.pdf
Any help?
Many thanks

On Page 789 we have:  QUOTE The regime variable can take three values, Zt ∈ E := {1, 2, 3} where {Zt = 1} means that volatility is in its low state, {Zt = 2} means it is in medium state, and {Zt = 3} means it is in a high state. END_QUOTE I hope this helps you.

@nbbo2 I see but there isn't a page 789

Internal page number 789 (see top right side of the page), the pdf page number is 3
